# Cant get rid off JumpTask item

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio, jump-list

I was just playing around with a JumpList in WPA app. I have added this code to my `App.xaml`:

```
<JumpList.JumpList>
    <JumpList ShowRecentCategory="False" ShowFrequentCategory="False">

        <JumpTask Title="New Note" Description="Create new note"
                  Arguments="/new" CustomCategory="Actions"/>
    </JumpList>  
</JumpList.JumpList>
```

Then i decided not to include that functionality in my app, so i removed those lines of code, but the item is still on the JumpList when i right click the taskbar icon.

I found solution that points to delete files from `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\`, but it didn't help.

Cleaning or rebuilding project didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried leaving the `<JumpList>` empty and running your application?

Comment: Richard, thanks a lot, that did the trick. Post this solution as an answer, i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you need to leave an empty `<JumpList>` in your application and run it once. You should then be able to remove the `<JumpList>` from your markup completely if required.

If the `<JumpList>` element isn't present, the code to update the jump list never executes, and Windows continues to use the previous jump list.

Comment: this works absolutely right for me!!                                 
 jumpList.JumpItems.Clear();
 jumpList.JumpItems.Add(new JumpTask()); 
 JumpList.SetJumpList(App.Current, jumpList);